Dynamically change physics whilst scrolling
It would be desirable to change the scroll physics whilst swiping. For example, when I would like to give vertical priority over horizontal priority when it comes to scrolling.
I have the following example that should illustrate the issue:

bool scrollable = false;
...

Listener(
  onPointerMove: (event) {
    setState(() {
      scrollable = true;
    });
  },
  onPointerPanZoomEnd: (event) {
    setState(() {
      scrollable = false;
    });
  },
  onPointerUp: (event) {
    setState(() {
      scrollable = false;
    });
  },
  onPointerCancel: (event) {
    setState(() {
      scrollable = false;
    });
  },
  child: TabBarView(
    physics: scrollable
        ? ClampingScrollPhysics()
        : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
  )
)

Assuming I drag horizontally on the tab bar view, the pointer move event is fired, which allows the scrollable variable to be changed. I would expect that the physics then changes to ClampingScrollPhysics rather than NeverScrollableScrollPhysics. This does actually happen but it requires the touch to be release and re-pressed to be able to make use of the new physics.
Is it possible for the existing pointer move event to be propagated with the new physics so the component starts scrolling as soon as the physics is changed?
The TabBarView's controller doesn't seem to have the capability to delegate the swipe, however extended_tabs does. I'm keen to see if there's a solution that doesn't require manual proxying of the pointer to programmatically drive the scrolling though; is that possible?
With thanks!

you might want to customScrollPhysics with snap position

Do you have an example? I had a play with trying to snap and didn't have the effect noted in the question sadly.
